# PL/SQL - payment system that dispenses exact change when necessary

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am currently trying to practice PL/SQL with a new procedure called 'Pay' that recognizes when you pay (based on parameter p_Paid) the amount equal to, less than, or greater than what was needed (based on parameter p_Price).

The difference of `p_Price` and `p_Paid` is variable `v_Return`.

When you pay the exact amount where `p_Paid = p_Price`, (for example, 10=10) then it should say

```
"No money to return!"
```

When you pay (`p_Paid`) less than what was asked (`p_Price`), then it should show the text

`"You're some short!"`

And when you pay (`p_Paid`) more than what was asked (`p_Price`), then it should give you change using 20, 10, 5, and 1 dollar bills and indicate the precise number of each type of bill, e.g. if `p_Paid` was 206 and `p_Price` was 10, then it should show the difference in exact change:

```
9 $20 bill(s)
1 $10 bill(s)
1 $5 bill(s)
1 $1 bill(s)
```

**This procedure assumes that everything is an integer (no cents involved).**

So far I have managed to get the procedure to recognize when the payment was equal to the price, or less than the price, *but I am having a horrible time trying to figure out how to get the money return part to work when they pay more than what was asked for*. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated; this is what I have so far (apologies in advance on how convoluted it may seem; I just started learning PL/SQL):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure Pay
(p_Price IN number,
p_Paid IN number)

AS
v_Return number;
v_20 number;
v_10 number;
v_5 number;
v_1 number;

BEGIN
v_Return := (p_Price - p_Paid);
v_20 := 0;
v_10 := 0;
v_5 := 0;
v_1 := 0;

IF v_Return = 0 THEN
dbms_output.put_line('No money to return!');
    ELSE
    IF p_Price > p_Paid THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('You're some short!');
        ELSE
        IF p_Price < p_Paid THEN
        WHILE v_Return > 20 LOOP
        v_Return := v_Return - 20;
        v_20 := v_20 + 1;
        IF v_Return > 10 THEN
        v_Return := v_Return - 10;
        v_10 := v_10 + 1;
        IF v_Return > 5 THEN
        v_Return := v_Return - 5;
        v_5 := v_5 + 1;
        IF v_Return > 1 THEN
        v_Return := v_Return - 1;
        v_Return := v_1;
        dbms_output.put_line(v_20 || '$20 bill(s)');
        dbms_output.put_line(v_10 || '$10 bill(s)');
        dbms_output.put_line(v_5 || '$5 bill(s)');
        dbms_output.put_line(v_1 || '$1 bill(s)');
END IF;
END IF;
END IF;
END LOOP;
END IF;
END IF;
END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: You are missing a quote in `'You're some short!'`. Also laying out your code neatly will help you focus on the structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're some errors in your code:

1. You need to escape that single quote in the `You're some short!` line, but I guess that's a copy-pasting error.
2. You're calculating `v_Return` backwards: you're substracting the payment from the price, so `v_Return` ends up being negative. Try `v_Return := (p_Paid - p_Price);`
3. Half your `END`s are wrongly placed, i.e. the `END LOOP;` line should be after the `v_20 := v_20 + 1;` line. Same goes for some of the `END IF;`s.
4. The last substraction when `v_Return` is already less than 5 is not necessary. Just assign the remaining amount to `v_1`.
5. And finally, though not an error *per se*, it's not a good idea to mix conditions, like you're doing using `v_Return` in the first `IF` but `p_Price` and `p_Paid` in the second and third `IF`s. If you had used `v_Return` you would have noticed that you were calculating it backwards since it would have printed "You're some short!" when it shouldn't.

EDIT: And now that you mention it, it's true that because you're checking `v_Return > x` instead of `v_Return >= x`, when `v_Return` is exactly `x` it won't notice that and will return change in lower units (one $5 and five $1 for $10 of change, instead of just one $10). So just use `>=`.

So your code should be like this (I tested it and it works OK):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure Pay
(p_Price IN number,
p_Paid IN number)

AS
v_Return number;
v_20 number;
v_10 number;
v_5 number;
v_1 number;

BEGIN
v_Return := (p_Paid - p_Price);
v_20 := 0;
v_10 := 0;
v_5 := 0;
v_1 := 0;

IF v_Return = 0 THEN
dbms_output.put_line('No money to return!');
    ELSE
    IF v_Return < 0 THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('You''re some short!');
        ELSE
        WHILE v_Return >= 20 LOOP
        v_Return := v_Return - 20;
        v_20 := v_20 + 1;
        END LOOP;
        IF v_Return >= 10 THEN
        v_Return := v_Return - 10;
        v_10 := v_10 + 1;
        END IF;
        IF v_Return >= 5 THEN
        v_Return := v_Return - 5;
        v_5 := v_5 + 1;
        END IF;
        v_1 := v_Return;
        dbms_output.put_line(v_20 || '$20 bill(s)');
        dbms_output.put_line(v_10 || '$10 bill(s)');
        dbms_output.put_line(v_5 || '$5 bill(s)');
        dbms_output.put_line(v_1 || '$1 bill(s)');
END IF;
END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The code definitely works now, but I just discovered that it doesn't do what I want. When I input, for example: exec(10,20), then it says 1 $5 bill(s) and 5 $1 bill(s) instead of the obvious 1 $10 bill(s). In other words, it over-complicates things. Do you have any suggestions on how to make it "smarter" to recognize to give larger bills first? Thank you again!

Comment: Sure, I'll edit my answer so you can accept it :) EDIT: there you go!

Comment: You're amazing! Thank you! I guess it doesn't help that I type all the code in a notepad file, haha. Will definitely have to look into a syntax editor that color-codes everything to catch errors like what happened to 'You''re.' EDIT: Works like a charm, thank you again walen! I'll study this code to learn more about how I can improve my next procedure.

Comment: If you're working with Oracle databases, you can download Oracle's SQL Developer for free.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, here's a more structured version. (The `money()` function that formats currency amounts and the `change()` procedure would be better as part of a package, but I've nested them inside the `pay()` procedure for demo convenience.)

```
create or replace procedure pay
    ( p_price pls_integer
    , p_paid  pls_integer )
as
    v_remainder pls_integer := p_paid - p_price;

    type change_list is table of pls_integer index by pls_integer;
    v_change change_list;

    function money
        ( p_amount pls_integer )
        return varchar2
    is
    begin
        return to_char(p_amount,'fmL99999');
    end money;

    procedure change
        ( p_amount in out nocopy pls_integer
        , p_denomination in pls_integer
        , p_change in out nocopy change_list )
    is
    begin
        if p_amount >= p_denomination then
            p_change(p_denomination) := trunc(p_amount/p_denomination);
            p_amount := mod(p_amount,p_denomination);
        else
            p_change(p_denomination) := 0;
        end if;

        dbms_output.put_line
        ( p_change(p_denomination) || ' ' || money(p_denomination) || ' bill' ||
          case when p_change(p_denomination) <> 1 then 's' end );
    end change;

begin
    if p_paid > p_price then
        dbms_output.put_line
        ( 'Price ' || money(p_price) ||
          ', Paid ' || money(p_paid) || ': Change due ' || money(v_remainder) || ', as:');

        change(v_remainder, 20, v_change);
        change(v_remainder, 10, v_change);
        change(v_remainder, 5, v_change);
        change(v_remainder, 1, v_change);
    else
        dbms_output.put_line
        ( case
              when p_paid = p_price then 'No change due.'
              else 'Please enter an additional '  || money(p_price - p_paid)
          end );
    end if;
end;
```

Example:

```
SQL> exec pay(73, 100)
Price $73, Paid $100: Change due $27, as:
1 $20 bill
0 $10 bills
1 $5 bill
2 $1 bills

SQL> exec pay(73, 50)
Please enter an additional $23
```

Note it becomes much easier to add a $50 bill.

The four calls to `change()` could be restructured as a loop, but then you'd have to construct the loop and you don't really gain much.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
v_20 := floor(v_return/20);
tmp:= v_return - v_20*20;
v_10 := floor(tmp/10);
tmp:= v_return - v_20*20 - v_10 * 10;
v_5 := floor(tmp/5);
v_1 := tmp - v_5*5;
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work in the procedure I want to make, thank you for trying though. Does anyone else have a solution please?

Comment: Why it not work in procedure? Please just add tmp to your local variables in procedure and it will work for section when p_paid>p_price